# A qué se debe el Error: label must be in [0, num_class)

Tags: r, packages

Estoy corriendo un modelo utilizando XGboost. Tengo el siguiente error:

> Error in xgb.iter.update(bst$handle, dtrain, iteration - 1, obj) : [12:23:02] amalgamation/../src/objective/multiclass_obj.cu:110: SoftmaxMultiClassObj: label must be in [0, num_class).

¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

El código es el siguiente:

```
answer <- train$fine_labels
remove <- c("fine_labels")
trainning2 <- train[!(names(train) %in% remove)]
trainning_matrix <- as.matrix(trainning2)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = trainning_matrix, label = answer)

set.seed(456)
nc <- length(unique(train$fine_labels))
nc <- as.numeric(as.character(nc))
xgb_params <- list("booster" = "gbtree", 
                   "eta" = 0.9944512, 
                   "max_depth" = 4, 
                   "subsample" = 0.8622684, 
                   "min_child_weight" = 0.7336961, 
                   "colsample_bytree" = 0.9545101, 
                   "gamma" = 8, 
                   "num_class" = nc - 1
)
model_xgb <- xgboost(data = dtrain, params = xgb_params, nrounds = 8, objective = "multi:softprob", eval_metric = "mlogloss")
pred <- predict(model_xgb, dtest)
```

Comment: Bienvenido @ María Raquel Gómez López a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al ver el reporte se indica que se está asignando a `dtrain` un label que no es soportado por la biblioteca **[`XGBoost`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/R-package/xgboostPresentation.html)**.

Si observas el enlace previo de la citada biblioteca, la variable `answer` que será el `label` de `dtrain`, debería ser un vector del tipo numérico `({0,1})` es decir el `[0, num_class)` que aparece en el reporte.

Por ejemplo `answer <- c("1","2")` tiene que garantizarse que empieza por `cero` y que sea del tipo numérico:

```
    answer <- as.numeric(answer)-1
    class(answer); answer
    "numeric"
    0 1
```

Comment: Gracias @HubertRonald por tu respuesta, efectivamente cambie el valor de las "classes" para que empezará desde cero y ha funcionado!